# using the value stored in the ._field attribute in python ast

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

This question is a result of my python ast work.

I have a node in the ast and I want to obtain its children.

The ._field attribute gives the names of all the children of a node. However it is different for different node depending upon the syntax node.

for example if node is of type BinOp..then node._field will yield ('left','op', 'right')

Hence to access the children of node I have to use node.left, node.op and node.right

But I want to do it for any general node.

given any node if I use node._field it will give me a tupple. How do I use this tupple for obtaining the children. The node can be any general node. So I do not know what the tuple would be like beforehand.

examples in form of codes will be really nice!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To iterate over the children of an arbitrary node, use [`ast.iter_child_nodes()`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.iter_child_nodes).  To iterate over the fields instead, use [`ast.iter_fields()`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.iter_fields).

Comment: Alternatively, use `ast.NodeVisitor` or `ast.NodeTransformer` to handle the tree traversal, and just implement the methods relevant to the nodes of interest.

Comment: thanks for your reply! i wrote the following code  st=ast.parse('5+a')                                                print ast.iter_child_nodes(st) .....                               output was <generator object iter_child_nodes at    0xb763de8>                                                         the output instead should have been the child of it.. an ast.expr object

Comment: @Adwait: These functions are meant to iterate over, so try `for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(st)`.